# Restrict network access for 1 user in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking

I have a ubuntu docker image where I need to restrict network access to only the programs run by 1 user.
I have other users on the docker image which need network access.

I already tried it with a iptables rule, but since I cannot modify the bare-metal server (and its OS) the image will be running on, that method did not work.

Is there a way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: A Docker container normally only runs one process, and a process only has a single user ID.  Can you describe a little bit more about your use case?  Is there a programming-related question – can you restrict outbound connections from your code itself – or is this more related to firewall configuration?

Comment: I have 1 "root" process in the docker container, which then runs multiple untrusted programs with a restricted user which can only access specific files, and I would also like to restrict network access for this user, but not the "root" process